# How to post blog programmatically on twitter

Tags: twitter, blogs

If anybody knows how to post blog programmatically directly on twitter, please let know. And is it possible to post a blog on twitter without linking up with another blog site?

Comment: Where is the connection to facebook? I don't understand at all what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

***Blog programmatically? What does that entail?***

Here are three solutions for posting to twitter from Vim for a start :)
[1. TwitVim : Twitter client for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2204)
[2. Twitter : A simple client for Twitter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1853)
[3. Twitter : Post to Twitter from Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2124)